# Terraform backend empty state

Tags: terraform

I am experiencing a weird behaviour with terraform. I have been working on an infra. I have a backend state configured to state my state file in a storage account in azure. Until yesterday everything was fine, this morning when I tried to update my infra, the output from `terraform plan` was weird as its trying to create all the resources as new, when I checked my local testate..it was empty.

I tried `terraform pull` and `terraform refresh` but nothing, still same result. I checked my remote state and I have all the resources still declared.

So I went for plan b, copy and paste my remote state into my local project and run terraform once again, but nothing, seems that terraform is ignoring my terraform state on my local and doesn't wanna pull the remote one.

EDIT:
this is the structure of my terraform backend:

```
terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name  = "<resource-group-name>"
    storage_account_name = "<storage-name>"
    container_name       = "<container-name>"
    key                  = "terraform.tfstate"
  }
}
```

The weird thing also, is that I just used terraform to create 8 resource for another project, and it did created everything and updated my backend state without any issue. The problem is only with the old resources.

Any help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you run `terraform workspace show` are you in the default workspace?
if you have the tfstate locally but you're not on the correct workspace terraform will ignore it : https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/state/workspaces.html#using-workspaces

also is it possible to see your backend file structure?

EDIT:
i dont know why it ignores your remote state, but i think that your problem is that when you run terraform refresh it ignores your local file because you have a remote config:

`Usage: terraform refresh [options]`

`-state=path - Path to read and write the state file to. Defaults to "terraform.tfstate". Ignored when remote state is used.`

`-state-out=path - Path to write updated state file. By default, the -state path will be used. Ignored when remote state is used.`

is it possible to see the ouput of your `terraform state pull`?

Comment: Hi Haroun, thank you so much for your reply. Yes I am in the default workspace. I will update my post and add the terraform backend

Comment: Solved Mate. Thank you very much for your time and help. I don't know how but it start working alone.